# Adding components to template dynamically(at run time) - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, components, angular2-template

I have a little problem with my system.
I'm trying to add a component that i've I created, to the template of another component, it goes like this:

1. I have a menu component which has many buttons, when each button is pressed it sends a parameter which indicate what type of information to show and redirect to some other page (to different url).
2. There, in the other page I take the parameter (which is a string), comparing in to a array and for each node in the array, which its key is the same as the parameter, I need to create an instance of my component with the relevance information and display it on the page.
   There maybe sometimes only one match and sometimes 4-6 matches.

My problem is that I can't understand how to put my component tag into this page template.

for example: my component called "viewInfo" and it get a paramter called "data", I want to add it to the template like this:

```
...
<viewInfo [data]='newData'></viewInfo>
...
...
```

So when I add it manually, it works, but in run-time I can never know how many node in the array will be the match the parameter.

Anyone has some kind of idea that could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for an example.

Comment: Use ngFor with new array that only contains the matched node. If none are matched it won't render anything

Comment: I had the same problem the error in thinking is that I was trying to implement it like React as you are doing. Angular does offer Dynamic Component Injection but it woulf get way complicated and had few bugs at the time I was trying it

Comment: Check this source if you decide to go with Dynamic Component Loading https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: read this article that explains dynamic components in depth [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com that is a good reason not to use angular.